# Flexible return type of method

Tags: java, android

I have a couple of classes (extending AsyncTaskLoader) that all basically do the same thing: make a REST call and create POJOs from the response with Gson. Now I thought it would be more elegant to have just one class (let it take some parameters) and just tell it what kind of object I expect to get back. As a parameter I would give the class of the POJO that I expect to get back because it is used in the Gson deserialization like

```
Imprint impr = gson.fromJson(responseString, Imprint.class);
```

What would be the return type of the class / method? I thought about letting it return `java.lang.Object` and then downcast it to the POJO type object that I expect, but is there a better possibility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use generics. An example method signature could look like

```
public <T> T callService(String parameters, Class<T> clazz)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use uwe solution, or just return the generic class(here asynctask),and then do a cast, or even return Object,and do a cast(more dangerous)

Comment: returning a plain generic class is almost as bad as returning Object

Comment: here I talk about returning a AsyncTaskLoader, wich is not plain generic,but pretty precise. the only differences between each child class are very small as he said,so not many risks are taken.